# Combine Date and Time in Django Queryset - TypeError

Tags: django

I am trying to combine date and time in my Django Queryset using `annotate`.

```
TimesheetEntry.objects.exclude(
    timesheet_is_running = False
).filter(
    timesheet_users__userprofile__user_company=request.user.userprofile.user_company
).annotate(
    timesheet_clock_in_time_date=datetime.datetime.combine('timesheet_clock_in_date', 'timesheet_clock_in_time')
).values_list(
    'timesheet_jobs__job_number',
    'timesheet_clock_in_time_date',
)
```

But it is giving me `TypeError`

> combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing date and time values to combine function, you are just providing strings **'timesheet_clock_in_date'** and **'timesheet_clock_in_time'** as arguments to combine function. To do the combine operation in database, you need to use F expressions together with ExpressionWrapper. You can find more info about these in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). Basically, you'll need to something like the following:

```
TimesheetEntry.objects.exclude(
    timesheet_is_running = False
).filter(
    timesheet_users__userprofile__user_company=request.user.userprofile.user_company
).annotate(
    timesheet_clock_in_time_date=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('timesheet_clock_in_date')+ F('timesheet_clock_in_time'),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
).values_list(
    'timesheet_jobs__job_number',
    'timesheet_clock_in_time_date',
)
```